# Prime tree game

Tags: combinatorics, primes

Let's play a game. On the first step you place the number 1. On the $n$-th step starting from $n=2$ you place the number $n$ such that:

- It is adjacent (horizontally or vertically) to one or more existing    numbers, either below or to the right of them.
- The sum of any pair of adjacent numbers is a prime.

For example, here is a game with 5 steps:

```
1-2-5
  |
  3
  |
  4
```

Note that here we cannot move 4 to the right of 3 as it would also be below 5 giving an invalid (non-prime) sum of 9.

What is the most number of steps that you can make in this game?

Comment: Dmitry, do you know (or at least believe that you know) the answer to this question?

Comment: I believe the current answer is correct, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: I share WhatsUp's suspicion that a proof is difficult and quite possibly beyond what today's mathematics is capable of.

Comment: I am now wondering if the *smallest* number of steps to complete a game is $\infty$

Comment: I can do it in 4 steps. 123 and 4 below 1. After that you cannot place 5.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer is PROBABLY

> infinity, i.e. one can continue this procedure forever.

I don't have a proof yet, but experimenting with it will yield something like

> [image]

My strategy is

> to go as deep as possible below the number $1$ (i.e. whenever a number can be added to that column, add it there), and then grow out "branches" to the right that are at least one row apart, so that they don't interfere with each other. The number $8$ in the image above is an exception.

Now my reasoning is that

> in view of the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), there are just "so many primes" that the procedure will likely become easier and easier, with more and more places that we can grow out the branches.

One idea to rigorously prove it is to use some result similar to

> [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate)

and reason that

> after the starting, the number of "branch growing positions" is always large enough to ensure the continuation of the game.
>
>
>  Note that according to the above strategy, the first column is totally determined. It's the sequence $(a_n)_n$ where $a_{n + 1}$ is the smallest integer larger than $a_n$ such that $a_n + a_{n + 1}$ is prime.
>
>
>  This sequence has logarithmic density by the prime number theorem, just as the sequence of primes. So at step $n$ we have about $n/2\log(n)$ growing positions, which is a lot!
>
>
>  There are of course many details to fill in, such as the parity problem. Therefore I don't think a rigorous solution would be easy.

---

EDIT:

There was an error in my picture above: I put $18$ to the right of $15$.

But this is very easy to correct. In the beginning you might need to manually change several values, but in my case I only encountered problem with $44$, in which case I moved $38$ down to the side of $21$. After that, everything is automatic. For example:

> This is one possible arrangement for $1$ to $999$:
>
> 1, 18
>
> 2, 5, 6, 11, 12, 17, 20, 23, 24, 29, 30, 41, 48, 49, 54, 59, 68, 71, 78, 85, 88, 93, 98, 99, 124, 127, 144, 149, 158, 159, 172, 175, 178, 181, 186, 187, 196, 205, 214, 217, 222, 227, 230, 233, 234, 245, 246, 253, 256, 265, 276, 281, 282, 287, 290, 303, 304, 313, 318, 323, 324, 329, 330, 343, 348, 353, 356, 363, 364, 369, 370, 373, 378, 383, 386, 401, 408, 413, 414, 425, 428, 431, 432, 445, 462, 467, 470, 483, 484, 487, 496, 501, 508, 513, 518, 521, 528, 533, 536, 551, 552, 557, 560, 563, 566, 585, 586, 595, 598, 603, 610, 613, 616, 621, 628, 631, 646, 657, 662, 665, 696, 703, 706, 721, 730, 741, 746, 747, 752, 759, 764, 767, 776, 777, 782, 785, 794, 803, 806, 807, 812, 815, 822, 835, 858, 863, 870, 871, 876, 877, 882, 895, 916, 945, 956, 957, 974, 975, 998, 999
>
> 3, 8
>
> 4, 9, 14, 15, 26, 27, 32, 35, 44, 45, 56, 57, 74, 75, 76, 81, 82, 97, 102, 109, 114, 119, 120, 131, 132, 137, 140, 143, 150, 161, 170, 179, 180, 193, 204, 215, 216, 241, 250, 259, 262, 279, 284, 285, 292, 295, 298, 301, 306, 307, 312, 319, 334, 339, 344, 347, 354, 355, 384, 385, 388, 399, 410, 411, 416, 423, 434, 443, 464, 465, 472, 475, 478, 489, 494, 497, 500, 509, 512, 519, 530, 531, 538, 549, 554, 555, 568, 583, 588, 593, 600, 601, 622, 627, 632, 645, 656, 663, 698, 701, 708, 715, 718, 729, 754, 757, 766, 783, 784, 787, 792, 809, 810, 817, 820, 837, 856, 865, 868, 873, 874, 879, 880, 897, 904, 907, 924, 943, 946, 961, 970, 979, 994
>
> 7
>
> 10, 19, 34, 39, 40, 43, 46, 61, 66, 73, 94, 103, 108, 125, 126, 145, 148, 163, 168, 169, 184, 189, 190, 199, 202, 207, 212, 219, 224, 225, 236, 243, 248, 251, 258, 263, 278, 293, 294, 299, 300, 317, 326, 327, 332, 341, 350, 351, 358, 361, 366, 367, 376, 381, 392, 395, 402, 407, 420, 437, 440, 441, 442, 469, 502, 507, 514, 517, 522, 527, 534, 535, 558, 559, 564, 565, 606, 607, 624, 625, 634, 643, 648, 649, 654, 667, 694, 705, 724, 735, 736, 753, 758, 765, 788, 791, 818, 819, 838, 855, 866, 867, 886, 891, 892, 909, 914, 933, 934, 939, 950, 951, 962, 969, 980, 993
>
> 13
>
> 16, 63, 64, 67, 72, 77, 80, 83, 96, 101, 110, 113, 116, 117, 122, 129, 134, 135, 146, 147, 164, 167, 206, 213, 218, 221, 228, 229, 238, 249, 254, 255, 266, 275, 288, 289, 394, 403, 406, 417, 422, 435, 446, 461, 468, 473, 474, 479, 488, 495, 524, 525, 526, 543, 544, 547, 570, 581, 582, 589, 592, 609, 614, 615, 644, 653, 666, 695, 704, 719, 720, 731, 740, 743, 744, 749, 750, 761, 762, 769, 774, 779, 780, 799, 802, 825, 832, 861, 862, 885, 898, 903, 908, 915, 932, 935, 938, 941, 948, 953, 954, 959, 972, 977, 996
>
> 21, 38
>
> 22, 315, 316, 337, 340, 393, 404, 405, 418, 421, 436, 447, 460, 481, 486, 491, 492, 505, 516, 523, 540, 569, 618, 619, 640, 661, 700, 709, 714, 733, 738, 755, 756, 797, 800, 801, 826, 831, 890, 893, 894, 929, 942, 947, 960, 971, 978, 995
>
> 25, 676
>
> 28, 33, 104, 107, 162, 239, 240, 269, 272, 335, 338, 345, 346, 397, 426, 427, 450, 457, 480, 503, 506, 515, 546, 571, 580, 591, 596, 597, 604, 633, 658, 669, 692, 737, 830, 833, 834, 859, 888, 889, 900, 901, 910, 913, 918, 983, 990
>
> 31
>
> 36, 53, 60, 139, 154, 183, 260, 261, 380, 389, 398, 455, 456, 485, 548, 575, 576, 577, 636, 641, 642, 659, 660, 713, 734, 789, 790, 823, 840, 853
>
> 37
>
> 42, 65, 86, 87, 92, 105, 106, 123, 128, 153, 194, 195, 268, 273, 274, 333, 454, 579, 608, 623, 626, 671, 690, 691, 796, 813, 814, 843, 850, 883, 928, 985, 988, 991
>
> 47, 62
>
> 50, 359, 360, 391, 396, 541, 672, 689, 710, 723, 728, 771, 772, 795, 824, 839, 854, 887, 902, 921, 926, 963, 968, 981, 992
>
> 51
>
> 52, 439, 448, 459, 482, 539, 578, 635, 668, 693, 860, 899, 912, 919, 982
>
> 55
>
> 58, 165, 166, 267, 320, 419, 438, 449, 458, 573, 590, 639, 680, 681, 686, 687, 712, 841, 852, 925, 964, 967, 984, 989
>
> 69, 574
>
> 70, 237, 242, 375, 452, 545, 572, 677, 684, 827, 842, 851
>
> 79
>
> 84, 95, 138, 155, 198, 203, 374, 377, 504, 605, 674, 699, 844, 849, 884, 927, 944, 987
>
> 89
>
> 90, 173, 174, 209, 210, 311, 336, 451, 678, 683, 770, 773, 798, 829
>
> 91
>
> 100, 711, 848, 911, 920
>
> 111, 152
>
> 112, 675, 922
>
> 115
>
> 118, 271, 390, 673, 688
>
> 121
>
> 130, 679, 682, 685, 846, 847
>
> 133
>
> 136
>
> 141, 542
>
> 142
>
> 151, 270
>
> 156
>
> 157
>
> 160, 453, 638, 845, 966
>
> 171
>
> 176
>
> 177, 314
>
> 182
>
> 185, 828
>
> 188
>
> 191
>
> 192, 637, 670
>
> 197
>
> 200, 923
>
> 201
>
> 208
>
> 211
>
> 220
>
> 223
>
> 226
>
> 231
>
> 232
>
> 235
>
> 244
>
> 247
>
> 252, 965, 986
>
> 257
>
> 264
>
> 277
>
> 280
>
> 283
>
> 286
>
> 291
>
> 296
>
> 297
>
> 302
>
> 305
>
> 308
>
> 309
>
> 310
>
> 321
>
> 322
>
> 325
>
> 328
>
> 331
>
> 342
>
> 349
>
> 352
>
> 357
>
> 362
>
> 365
>
> 368
>
> 371
>
> 372
>
> 379
>
> 382
>
> 387
>
> 400
>
> 409
>
> 412
>
> 415
>
> 424
>
> 429
>
> 430
>
> 433
>
> 444
>
> 463
>
> 466
>
> 471
>
> 476
>
> 477
>
> 490
>
> 493
>
> 498
>
> 499
>
> 510
>
> 511
>
> 520
>
> 529
>
> 532
>
> 537
>
> 550
>
> 553
>
> 556
>
> 561
>
> 562
>
> 567
>
> 584
>
> 587
>
> 594
>
> 599
>
> 602
>
> 611
>
> 612
>
> 617
>
> 620
>
> 629
>
> 630
>
> 647
>
> 650
>
> 651
>
> 652
>
> 655
>
> 664
>
> 697
>
> 702
>
> 707
>
> 716
>
> 717
>
> 722
>
> 725
>
> 726
>
> 727
>
> 732
>
> 739
>
> 742
>
> 745
>
> 748
>
> 751
>
> 760
>
> 763
>
> 768
>
> 775
>
> 778
>
> 781
>
> 786
>
> 793
>
> 804
>
> 805
>
> 808
>
> 811
>
> 816
>
> 821
>
> 836
>
> 857
>
> 864
>
> 869
>
> 872
>
> 875
>
> 878
>
> 881
>
> 896
>
> 905
>
> 906
>
> 917
>
> 930
>
> 931
>
> 936
>
> 937
>
> 940
>
> 949
>
> 952
>
> 955
>
> 958
>
> 973
>
> 976
>
> 997
>
>
>  As you can see, there are already quite a lot of "spares" in the bottom.

With a program, I have verified that

> It works at least until $10^5$. So, hopefully forever.

Comment: I doubt this. The issue is that the frequency of primes decreases while the area for attachment increases linearly.

Comment: @DrXorile I have edited to give an example to convince you.

Comment: Why doesn't 22 go in between 7,9,19?

Comment: @JMP My algorithm goes like this: first try to put it on the first colum; then try to put it on even-indexed rows; finally try to put it on odd-indexed rows. This way mostly only the even-indexed rows grow, so that they separate automatically.

Comment: @WhatsUp, i see you're point. Slots available is ~N and density is log(N)